# opening a fold and jumping to end of it in vim

Tags: vim, folding

When I open a fold in vim by zo, I am at starting of opening fold. Then I need to usually jump to end of fold by ]z. Is there any single command for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but you can create a keymapping if you like.

`nmap z] zo]z`

`nmap z[ zo[z`